# How to update a mysql table in 2 databases at once using php

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, database, sql-update

I have a laravel application A with a mysql database db1 and a table p1 and a diffrent php application B with an equivalent table p2 in its mysql database db2.
I want to find best, secure and complete way to update at least from application B both p1 in db1 and p2 in db2.
I have some columns only in p1, some columns only in p2 and some common columns but the rows have a one on one equivalence never one to many. It is the same entity from real world.

1. Main question

I have thought of doing an edit form in application B with a transaction in which i update both tables with their respective columns and the new values but will this block the records from both database ? What do I have to worry about?

2. Extra scenario

2.1. start transaction
2.2. I update a fk column in p1 in db1 and it works
2.3. By the time i finish the transaction someone deletes in application a the row in fk coresponding table f1.id=p1.fk
2.4. I make the update in database db2 where there is no fk column ;
2.5. I should commit or will it give me an error (as it should) that the first update cannot be performed ?

3. Clarification 1

What if i also want to implement and edit form in application A will same solution apply? Should i update only in one application ?

4. Clarification 2

What settings like isolation level should I use and how ? A code example would be very helpful.

I am opened to suggestions on how to do this task. Thank you.

```
start transaction

UPDATE db1.p1 pp1 inner join db2.p2 pp2 on pp1.iddb2=pp2.id
    SET 
       pp1.fk_id=23,
       pp1.commoncol='a',
       pp2.commoncol='a',
       pp2.extracol='b'
WHERE pp2.id=123;

commit;
```

Comment: can you write your question in bullets?

Comment: Is this 2 Separate Laravel Application with separate database and you want to create/update/delete records on both mysql db?

Comment: @Mr. Kenneth
  There are 2 different existing aplications one in laravel and another in core php each with their own database and i am focusing on implementing update in a sinchronized manner.  But of course create and delete should be considered.

Comment: does the database have the same structure? Why not make both laravel and core php to connect to the same database? Maybe host to RDS or make your laravel app connect to your core php's database. That way both will have only 1 db

Comment: @Mr. Kenneth My databases are similar and I could make one comon database but then i would have to add columns and tables to both existing databases and apps. I don't know if that won't break the existing apps: laravel 8 app and core php. It is not exactly the same database. Moving all core php app and laravel 8 app in laravel 10 common app with one database is also considered but it would take a lot of time and effort so I thought this update on two main more important tables in synchronized manner would take less time for now.

Comment: Just one question. Are DBs of Laravel and Core PHP have the same data? Or you just want to pass data from Laravel to Core and vice versa when needed?

Comment: @Mr. Kenneth They have same data it could be one big app but now there are two separate apps with different functionalities.

Comment: I meant the database. Is it essentially a clone with just different database hosted in different server or do they only share data when needed?

Comment: @Mr. Kenneth I don't think it's an exact clone because client said there are differences in columns and tables. But the tables have same meaning in both databases. For example products table is same but probably with some extra columns in one db.

Comment: Got it. you could try to use `curl` in your methods. From laravel, when you have successfully saved your data, execute a `curl` method that will submit a `POST` request to your corePHP, updating the DB in corePHP. Then vice versa.

Comment: In curl, make sure you add your params. You will also need to create dedicated routes for both laravel and core PHP for this communication. Downside is it will take more time to process your request. ex: In laravel, you update a record in laravel DB, then curl to corePHP to update DB, wait for the response from corePHP back to laravel and then return response from Laravel controller back to blade. Since there is no async in PHP, it will need to wait response from curl before continuing

Comment: Plus side, you dont call core PHP db from laravel and you dont call laravel db from core php so you can debug per application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a problem *if the two dbs are in the same MySQL instance*, but...

- A transaction is "all" or "none".
- A transaction must be run from a single connection.  And both databases must be in the same MySQL instance.  (Let's not talk about "two-phase commit".)  If, by "database", you mean "server", then make that abundantly clear in the Question.
- Other connections are prevented from modifying anything involved in the transaction.
- You should not need to watch what other connections are doing, but...
- You do need to check for errors.  One connection can interfere with another, and the system will abort one transaction.  Generally, start the killed transaction over.
- Use the default transaction isolation.
- Whether a column is a Foreign Key is irrelevant to this discussion.
- If, inside a transaction, you need to `SELECT` some data before deciding what to do, use `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`.  (I don't know how Laravel exposes this option.)

(I agree with the Comments that having two databases and syncing them may be 'over-thinking' the task.)

Answer (score -2):

Making changes to data in two separate databases at the same time while ensuring that the data stays consistent can be a tricky job.

If you're utilizing Laravel's Eloquent, you can utilize the DB::transaction method to group your updates into a transaction.

Here's an example in Laravel:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

DB::transaction(function () {
    // Your database updates for application B
    // Update in db1.p1
    // Update in db2.p2
});
```

In your scenario, if you modify the foreign key in p1 first, and someone deletes the corresponding row in db1 before updating p2 in db2, you may encounter difficulties in maintaining the association between them, referred to as referential integrity issues.

Comment: Thank you for your replys and comments. It's two databases on same server who share this one table p with same name but different columns, some common, some with no equivalent in the other database. I will chose between making one common database or synchronizing the p table in both.